# Firing an Angular 2 Attribute Directive after model load

Tags: angular

I'm trying to create a number input that always displays 3 decimal places.  So if a value of 1.1 would show as 1.100.  I've created a directive that responds to the blur event and it works well but I'm having trouble getting the formatting to fire if the ngModel is passing a value at load time.

When I check the DOM element value in ngOnInit it's not set yet.  I've tried capturing the value from the model itself rather than the DOM setting the DOM element value in the Init function as well, but then that gets overwritten after the init event with the non 3 decimal place value.

The following code demonstrates this (an unpadded number 3 loads to the input, if you click in and out, the value will change to 3.000:  https://embed.plnkr.co/L1wxZN8n8tGvWU51KLcj/

I can't find an event to bind to that fires after the model value has been propagated the to input the first time.  I suppose I could use a timeout but I thought I would ask to see if I was missing some base concept in Angular 2.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `AfterViewChecked` hooks:

```
import { Directive, HostListener, ElementRef, OnInit, AfterViewChecked } from "@angular/core";

@Directive({ selector: "[fixeddecimal]" })
export class FixedDecimalDirective implements OnInit, AfterViewChecked {

    private el: HTMLInputElement;

    constructor(
        private elementRef: ElementRef
    ) {
        this.el = this.elementRef.nativeElement;
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.onBlur(0);
    }

    ngAfterViewChecked() {

        this.onBlur(0);
    }
    @HostListener("blur", ["$event.target.value"])
    onBlur(value) {
        let inputVal: number = +this.el.value;
        this.el.value = inputVal.toFixed(3).toString();
        //    this.el.value = this.currencyPipe.transform(value);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Implement DoCheck lifecycle hook that will be triggered after ngOnInit is triggered. You can use this lifecycle hook to trigger updates that are failed to initialize by angular2.

```js
import { Directive, HostListener, ElementRef, DoCheck } from "@angular/core";

@Directive({ selector: "[fixeddecimal]" })
export class FixedDecimalDirective implements DoCheck  {

  private el: HTMLInputElement;

  constructor(
    private elementRef: ElementRef
  ) {
    this.el = this.elementRef.nativeElement;
  }

  
  
  ngDoCheck() {
    let inputVal : number = +this.el.value;
    this.el.value =  inputVal.toFixed(3).toString();
  }
  

  @HostListener("blur", ["$event.target.value"])
  onBlur(value) {
    let inputVal : number = +this.el.value;
    this.el.value =  inputVal.toFixed(3).toString();
  }

}
```

Comment: I  was actually just fooling around with that event.  It would seem to get fired quite a bit and then ends up really impacting the input functionality of the box.  Is there anyway to unregister the event handler after I've detected the change I want?

Answer (score 1):

I implemented my ngDoCheck with a private boolean to keep track if the value has been applied.

```
private onLoadCheck: boolean = false;

ngDoCheck() {
    // check if value is applied on init
    if (this.el.value && this.el.value > 0) {
        if (!this.onLoadCheck) {
            let inputVal: any = +this.el.value;
            this.el.value = this.currencyPipe.transform(inputVal);
            this.onLoadCheck = true;
        }
    }
}
```